# Calculus III find limit recursively defined sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image: Question 1]

Attached is the question above, it's pretty straightforward and I know it converges to 2, I'm just not sure how to show it by taking the limit.

Comment: Please put all relevant information in the body of the question as opposed to links.

Comment: "it's pretty straightforward and I know it converges to 2" could you tell us why you would think so? Including context may help others help you better, and will also help prevent your question from being closed.

Comment: It converges to 2 (educated guess) because when you plug in a1, a2, a2 etc etc into the formula it keeps getting closer to 2.

Comment: When plugging in those numbers, you might've noticed that:$$a_1<a_3<\dots<2<a_4<a_2$$which may help...

Comment: Oops, the inequality should be$$a_1<a_3<\dots<2<\dots<a_4<a_2$$

Comment: I understand that each odd An is below 2 and each even An is above 2 but both moving closer to 2, but I'm still confused to how to show this as a limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$a_n>2\implies a_{n+2}=\cfrac{12}{4+\cfrac{12}{4+a_n}}>\cfrac{12}{4+\cfrac{12}{4+2}}=2$$

Since

$$x>y>0\implies\underbrace{\frac{12}{4+x}}_u<\underbrace{\frac{12}{4+y}}_v\implies\frac{12}{4+u}>\frac{12}{4+v}$$

We also have

$$a_n>2\implies a_{n+2}=\cfrac{12}{4+\cfrac{12}{4+a_n}}<a_n$$

Since

\begin{align}x>2&\implies12(4+x)<4x(4+x)+12x\\&\implies12<\left(4+\frac{12}{4+x}\right)x\\&\implies\cfrac{12}{4+\cfrac{12}{4+x}}<x\end{align}

The proof that $-4<a_n<2\implies a_n<a_{n+2}<2$ is very similar and left up to the reader.

From this, we may deduce that since $a_{2n}$ is bounded and monotone, it must converge to a limit. Likewise for $a_{2n+1}$. This limit must satisfy $a_1<L=\frac{12}{4+L}<a_2$, and so the limit is indeed $2$.

Comment: this helped, thanks!

Comment: @Liam Since you've never casted a vote and you've never accepted any answers, I'd like to take a moment to mention that [voting is good for the community](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/662/272831) and that [accepting answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10626/the-feature-of-accepting-answers-necessary) likewise has its own benefits.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want is to calculate the limit (not to show it, in fact, exists) then if $\alpha=\lim(a_n)$ and taking limits on both sides of the equation yields $$\lim(a_{n+1})=\frac{12}{4+\lim(a_n)} \Leftrightarrow \alpha =\frac{12}{4+\alpha} \Leftrightarrow \alpha^2+4\alpha-12=0 \Leftrightarrow (\alpha+6)(\alpha-2)=0. $$ From there you have that $\alpha=2$ or $\alpha=-6$. Why can't $\alpha=-6$ be the limit you are looking for?